Is this gym routine that bad?
Due to time constrains and job change, I have had to change my workout routine. In the past three months I started using the routine below where each two exercise are supersets. I do two days exercise then two days rest & repeat with each exercise of three sets. However, I keep getting weird looks and comments for some people like you are doing too much and and should only focus on two muscles a day .. etc. Is this really that bad?


Full body workout is a thing, don't worry. Focusing on "2 muscle a day" can be better for some people but not for other. I also do it because having longer session but on less days of the week fit better on my schedule. Some other people like shorter session and go to gym 6 days  a week and it's fine too ! I'm not so good at reviewing exercises split though so I'll let other people answer.
